# CBB inequality and two comparison triangles / 4-point condition for CBB spaces

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, alexandrov-geometry

Assume $(X,d)$ is a CBB($\kappa$) space with $\kappa > 0$. (That is we can find comparison triangles in the model space $(M_\kappa^2, \bar{d})$ and the reverse of the CAT inequality holds; Definition 5.1.12 in Lipschitz Functions - Ştefan Cobzaş, Radu Miculescu, Adriana Nicolae).

Now my question is the following. Assume there are $4$ points $x,y, z_1, z_2$ in $X$ and we take comparison triangles $\Delta(\bar{x},\bar{y},\bar{z_1})$ and $\Delta(\bar{x},\bar{y},\bar{z_2})$ in $M^2_\kappa$ such that the distance between $\bar{z_1}$ and $\bar{z_2}$ becomes minimal. Under what conditions does it hold that $d(z_1, z_2) \geq \bar{d}(\bar{z_1}, \bar{z_2})$?

Comment: I think this follows directly from Kirszbraun theorem in Alexandrov spaces...